# Стеганография. Что можно прятать в изображениях, аудиозаписях и видеозаписях кроме текста?

Tags: стеганография

Можно ли спрятать картинку в другой картинке? Можно ли спрятать картинку в видеозаписи? Можно ли спрятать видеозапись в другой видеозаписи?

Comment: Можно, если можете спрятать текст base64 вас спасет

Answer (score 9):

Все можно спрятать. Но смотря, что Вы подразумеваете под словом `спрятать`?

1. `Например, как спрятать картинку (первой изображение) в другой картинке (во втором изображении)?` Берем второе изображение достаточно больших размеров (имеются ввиду не метры, а пикселы) по отношению к первому (чем больше, тем лучше). Желательно, чтобы второе изображение не было однотонным, а было как можно более пестрым. Пусть первое изображение будет, например, размером 100х100px. А второе изображение, например, 5000х5000px. `Разбиваем` первое изображение по пикселам. Каждый пиксел первого изображения помещаем вместо каждого 50-го пиксела второго изображения. В итоге имеем одно изображение - второе. Но глазом Вы никогда не "соберете" первого изображения и не скажете, что второе какое-то странное. Спрятали? Спрятали.
2. `Как спрятать картинку (изображение) в видеозаписи?` Видеозапись есть ничто иное как набор изображений показываемых нам поочередно с очень большой скоростью. Из-за инертности зрения каждый кадр в отдельности сливается с подобным и не выделяется человеком. Поэтому достаточно будет подменить какой-либо один отдельный кадр в видеозаписи своей картинкой. Конечно же желательно, чтобы по цветовой гамме, тональности и т.п. она совпадала с аналогичными параметрами заменяемого кадра. И, желательно, чтобы она заменяла кадр в динамичной видеозаписи. Думаете, что Вы заметите такую картинку? Вряд ли. Вот ее и спрятали.
3. `Ну и как спрятать видеозапись в видеозаписи?` Использовать один из вышеперечисленных методов. Видеозапись - ничто иное как набор изображений. Можно отдельные изображения одной видеозаписи прятать на отдельных изображениях второй (см. пункт 1). Либо же вставлять отдельные изображения одной видеозаписи между отдельными изображениями второй видеозаписи (см. пункт 2). Успех будет зависеть от размеров кадров, длин видеозаписей, их качества, динамичности и т.д. и т.п.

Answer (score 4):

Спрятать можно любую последовательность байт. Размер последовательности зависит лишь от алгоритма сокрытия и размера контейнера.

Большинство стеганографических алгоритмов (кроме самых примитивных) не зависят от того, как вы интерпретируете ту последовательность байт, которую пытаетесь сокрыть.